# PHP Unexpected runtime added dynamic property

Tags: php, json

I have Class function that convert simple Associative array to json and then insert json to db example: {"ArrayKey":"ArrayContent","NextArrayKey":"NextArrayContent",etc...} but when I receive and decode json to be used I expect array instead I get runtime added dynamic property. I mean I dont have issue to access it example: $className->UserArrayContent->ArrayKey;   Can someone explain me this behavior ?

example code

```
    //Insert array as json to DB
    public function array_to_db(Request $request){
         // validation of $request ... 
        $ArrayContent = [$valid->key =>$valid->content];
        $set = ['ArrayContent'=>json_encode($ArrayContent)];
        $stmt = $this->_db->update('DBtable')->set($set)->where('memberID',$this->_member->memberID)->execute();
        // rest of function ...
    }
   //Get data when needed
   public function getUserArrayData(){
        $stmt = $this->_db->from('DBtable')->where('memberID',$this->memberID)->execute();
        $result =  $stmt->fetchAll('ArrayContent','Username','ProfileImg');
        // expected to be array 
        $this->UserArrayContent = json_decode($result['ArrayContent']);
        //rest of the function ...
   }
```

example: When I debug class property UserArrayContent

```
"0" => {#37 ▼
    +"ArrayKey": "ArrayContent"
    +"NextArrayKey": "NextArrayContent"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `json_decode` returns an object with the previos keys as properties. If you want to get back an array, pass `true` as a second parameter. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Every day you can learn something new thanks =)